# Plotting wind vectors (or wind barbs) in a 1-D chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have arrays containing wind magnitude and wind direction for a given point over time. I would like to plot them both on the same graph, displaying wind magnitude with a line and wind direction as vectors (or wind barbs) in the middle. I have done this before with other plotting softwares but this time I need to do it in matplotlib.

Below is a reference for the plot needed, using wind barbs

[image: reference plot]

Comment: If what you call "edit" is actually the solution to the problem, it should not be part of the question, but an answer. You can answer your own question and accept it after 2 days, such that this question is solved.

Comment: thanks, did just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked igrolvr's answer and got something pretty nice looking I think

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK6o7.png)

```
obs_times = pd.to_datetime(debertWeatherStation['Date/Time (LST)'])
wind_speed = debertWeatherStation['Wind Spd (km/h)']
wind_direction = debertWeatherStation['Wind Dir (10s deg)']*10.0

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(obs_times,wind_speed,'-b',alpha=0.6)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.grid()
plt.title("Wind Speed")
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2,sharex=ax1)
arrow_scaler = 1
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(wind_speed.min(),wind_speed.max(), len(wind_speed)))
for i in range(0,len(obs_times),1):
    u = arrow_scaler*-1*np.sin((np.pi/180)*(wind_direction[i]))
    v = arrow_scaler*-1*np.cos((np.pi/180)*(wind_direction[i]))
    ax2.arrow(obs_times[i], 0, u, v, fc=colors[int(wind_speed[i])], ec='k', 
              head_width=0.2, head_length=0.5, width=0.2, length_includes_head=True, 
              alpha=0.6)
plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
plt.grid()
plt.title("Wind Direction")
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to plot using `arrow` functionality of matplotlib. The tricky part was that my wind direction is in meteorological convention (0˚ = N, 90˚ = E, 180˚ = S, 270˚ = W), so I needed to compute the `u` and `v` components accordingly.

`obs_times`, `wind_speed` and `wind_direction` are my arrays containing the observation times and wind data, plot code is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize=(18, 4))
ax.plot(obs_times, wind_speed, linewidth=2, color='blue')
arrow_scaler = 3
for i in xrange(0,len(obs_times),4):
    u = arrow_scaler*-1*np.sin((np.pi/180)*(wind_direction[i]))
    v = arrow_scaler*-1*np.cos((np.pi/180)*(wind_direction[i]))
    ax.arrow(obs_times[i], (wind_speed.max()+2)/2, u, v, fc='k', ec='k', head_width=0.4, head_length=0.6)
```

This gives the output (yes, my data is noisy, that's fine):

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [quiver](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) -- [as in this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html) -- work for your case.
You just need to define vectors, not matrices.
Follow an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

X=np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2)
Y=np.ones(X.shape)
U= np.cos(X)
V= np.sin(X)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(X,X,'--')
Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, Y, Y, units='width') 
Q = plt.quiver(X, Y-2, U, V, units='width')
plt.show()
```

which gives this result

[image: Quivers]

Comment: I tried that, it's close but unfortunately doesn't help. Thanks

Comment: It does not plot the arrows or something else?

Comment: Those example are for 2D plots, I couldn't leverage it for a 1D plot. The logic is very different

Comment: It does work, you just need to define the vector properly. I'm updating the post.

Comment: I had better luck using `arrow`. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Good to hear :) . Actually, better to post your solution as answer and accept it. In this way the question is considered solved (unless you expect another solution).